# Redirect subdirectory and link to appropriate links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have links like this

```
http://example.com/sub-directory/1111-product-link.html
```

where 1111 can be any number

I want to set up a 301 redirect rule to redirect them to

```
http://example.com/product-link-1111.html
```

and so far no clue without regular redirects 301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in /.htaccess file :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub-directory/([0-9]+)-product-link\.html$  http://example.com/product-link-$1.html
```